# "Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of null" error. when trying to make API call with 'aws-Amplify'

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

First time after installing the application and when trying to make API requests getting 'accessKeyId' of null" error, once the application is terminated and restarted all API requests are working fine.

aws-amplify configuration below.

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: 'xxx', 
        identityPoolId: 'xxx',
        userPoolId: 'xxx', 
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xxx',
    },
    API: {
        endpoints: [
            {
                name: "xxx",
                endpoint: "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

AWS authentication configuration below

```
AWS.config.update({ region: "xxx",accessKeyId:"xxx",secretAccessKey:"xxx" });

    export const poolData = {
      UserPoolId: "xxx",
      ClientId: "xxx",
    };

    export const userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Using "react-native-aws-cognito-js : 0.0.7" for authentication and "aws-amplify:^0.2.3" for API calls

[This is the error appears for the first time when API request is made using aws-amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9opB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the latester version of aws-amplify which is 0.2.14?